# Efficient Euclidean distance in h2o with R

Tags: r, h2o

I have a big hex frame in H2O, for which I need to compute euclidean distance between the two points that are in each row. Although it produces the correct result, the following H2O R code runs too slowly. 30 minutes have elapsed already and it is still running.  I even had time to post this question to stackoverflow while it runs.

Is there a more efficient design possible for this h2o code?

```
# H2O R code to row-wise compute Euclidean distance between two points s1 and s2 contained in each row.
# Is this the most efficient H2O code that is possible? Real world will run on a big hex frame.
h2odistance = function(hex, cols1, cols2) {
    nr = h2o.nrow(hex)
    for (r in 1:nr) {
        dif = hex[r,cols1] - hex[r,cols2]
        sq = dif * dif
        sm = h2o.sum(sq)
        rt[r] = h2o.sqrt(sm)
    }
    rt  
}
```

Here is plain old R code of it, for comparison. I am including a small test case dataframe for correctness checking:

```
(df = data.frame(s1_c1=c(1,3), s1_c2=c(2,20), s1_c3=c(3,3), s2_c1=c(9,21), s2_c2=c(10,22), s2_c3=c(0,0)))
fn <- function(z) {sqrt(sum((z[1:3] - z[4:6])^2))}
(rt = apply(df, 1, fn))
```

This is the correct output of the plain R code for reference:

11.7046999107196 18.3575597506858

The h2o code outputs the correct value too:

```
h2odistance(as.h2o(df), 1:3, 4:6)
```

11.7046999107196 18.3575597506858

Comment: Please notice that this is NOT an all-pairs distance computation.  It is just nrow(df) distances being computed.  This is not a nearest neighbor search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `h2o.distance()` function for this with `measure = "l2"`, which has recently been committed to the master branch but is not released yet.  To use it you need to [build H2O from master](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3#Building).  An example of how to use the function is [here](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-r/tests/testdir_munging/runit_distance.R).

Comment: I get memory error: Not enough free memory to allocate the distance matrix (404279 rows and 404279 cols.   See, you seem to be making an all-pairs distance matrix. But it's a bad assumption -- I did not want an all-pairs computation.  I just want distance between the two points as defined by the x frame and the y frame.  The implementation is making bad assumption about all-pairs.  Perhaps you had nearest neighbors in mind, but NN is definitely not the only thing distance computation is good for.  I just have 2 points per frame row to compute the distance on.

Answer (score 1):

you can also try downloading the latest nightly build from http://h2o.ai/download, and here's a test for that distance function in R:

https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/277ce7d3bd14514b5c34bc58c18514011256f533/h2o-r/tests/testdir_munging/runit_distance.R

Comment: I got a memory error.  (see comment to Erin).  Why is h2o.distance making an all-pairs computation?  I do not want that in the general case of computing a distance.  Of course h2o cannot allocate a square matrix in dense format of 404279 x 404279. I just want distance between 2 points (100-d in my case) in each row.  No all-pairs stuff here.  An exhaustive nearest neighbors search is not necessarily why users want to make distance computations. Bad idea to attempt exhaustive NN search on huge number of point-pairs -- approximate methods are suitable at this scale, like balltree and LSH.

Answer (score 0):

This expression should do the trick:
`sqrt(apply((hex[,cols1] - hex[,col2])^2, 1, sum))`

Comment: Or: `sqrt(h2o.sum((hex[,cols1] - hex[,cols2])^2, axis = 1, return_frame = TRUE))`